# Dynamically added div as droppable, ng-repeat and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was have a div basically it is generated by angularjs using ngrepeat like this

```
var templateElemUrl = '';
        $http({url: templateElemUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: '',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //check if the response has ok status
            if(data.status == "ok"){
                $scope.templateElements = data.data;
                droppable(); //make this div droppable
                console.log(data.data);
            }


            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log('error');

        });
```

I used the scope templateElements details to create the divs, basically it contain the size of the div would be.

then every div I create i put class `droppable` then i call the function `droppable()` just to land to this code :

```
function droppable(){
    console.log('here');
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: ".draggableItem",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
             console.log('dropped');
        }
    });
```

and my div i dont include the inline style cos it look messy but it goes like this

```
<div data-ng-repeat="tempElement in templateElements" class="droppable" >{{tempElement.divname}}</div>
```

could anyone help me? any comments and idea is well appreciated.

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize dropable elements in directive (directives are commonly used to integrate jquery plugins into angular apps):

```
app.directive('droppable', function() {
  return {
      link: function (scope, element) {
         $(element).droppable({
            accept: ".draggableItem",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                 console.log('dropped');
            }
        });
      } 
    }
  };
});
```

html:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="tempElement in templateElements" class="droppable" droppable>{{tempElement.divname}}</div>
```

data binding:

```
var templateElemUrl = '';
        $http({url: templateElemUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: '',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //check if the response has ok status
            if(data.status == "ok"){
                $scope.templateElements = data.data;
                //droppable(); //remove this line
                console.log(data.data);
            }


            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log('error');

        });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xro0COmAJ8mA5ONaILjC?p=preview

Comment: sir @MajoB you mean normal initiation of droppable like in jquery may not work when the div is created via angular esp. ng-repeat?

Comment: @caffeineshots yes, you have to always wrap jquey code into directive.

Comment: Sir @MajoB thanks for that info I am beginner to angular, wait I will just give it a try.

Comment: how to get directive to work? i added the app.directive still the div is not droppable. maybe i am missing something

Comment: @caffeineshots i setup a punker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/Xro0COmAJ8mA5ONaILjC?p=preview